# Sorting SQL bookmarks

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was wondering if theres anyway to sort the query/queries bookmarks in phpmyadmin SQL

As you can see the in picture its unsorted, or sorted in a way I want to change (If anyone can edit my post to view the picture considering I dont have enough reputation to post it, would be appreciated)

[image]

Any suggestions to improve my questions would be appreciated.

Comment: It's sorted alphabetically, not numerically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 digits for all your numbers, i.e. 00, 01, 02, 03, instead of 1, 2, 3, etc.