# How can I sort my bookmarked SQL queries in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, phpmyadmin

how can I sort my bookmarked SQL queries in phpmyadmin? It is becoming harder to find a query with more and more queries bookmarked.

I couldn't find any solution anywhere. I found [question about being sorted alphabetically, not numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197051/sorting-sql-bookmarks), but my queries are not sorted at all. Is there a (easy) way to sort them?

I'm using phpmyadmin 4.6.6.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: HINT:  `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Eric But how can I access them?

Comment: Ok. If I run this query `SELECT * FROM phpmyadmin.pma__bookmark ORDER BY phpmyadmin.pma__bookmark.label` it gives me ordered table. But the drop down menu is still unsorted. Can I sort the queries in the menu?